# Does Google Maps Javascript API v3 Geocoding Library overwrite localStorage keys with keys starting with "geocode:"?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, google-geocoding-api

I have Google Maps Javascript API v3 on a page and am using the Geocoding Library:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

**The Code**
In my `google.maps.Geocoder.geocode` callback function I am saving the lat,lng as JSON into the Chrome browser's `window.localStorage` like this:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('geocode:'+job.url) === null) {
    geocoder.geocode({'address': job.address}, function(results, status) {
        var json = JSON.stringify({
            address: job.address,
            lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
            lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng()
        });
        console.log('Set key:"geocode:'+job.url+'", value: '+json);
        localStorage.setItem('geocode:'+job.url, json);
        console.log('Get key:"geocode:'+job.url+'", value: '+localStorage.getItem('geocode:'+job.url));
    });
}
```

**The problem** is my key is getting set to null outside the callback function.
After the above code runs and prints the two log messages, typing this in the Console shows the problem:

```
> localStorage.length;
  1
> localStorage.key(0);
  "geocode:123 street San Francisco CA USA"
> localStorage.getItem("geocode:123 street San Francisco CA USA");
  null
```

Changing my localStorage key prefix to 'blah:' fixes the problem!

Does this mean the Google Maps Javascript API v3 Geocoding Library overwrites localStorage keys with a prefix "geocode:" after the callback function returns?

**Extra background info:**

I am including this script code on the page from a Chrome extension url like:

```
<script src="chrome:///blah" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The call to `google.maps.Geocoder.geocode` and the callback function are called from a `window.setTimeout` handler.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem, can you include a demo?

Comment: This may be a dumb idea - but why not clear out your localstorage and make use of the Google Maps API. Then in console, just dump out the values in localstorage and see if Google wrote to it.